# Adjust regex to ignore anything else inside link HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

So I have this regex:

```
<a(?:.*)href="(.*)"(?:.*)>(.*)<\/a>
```

So far I have been able to get it to match HTML link tags that have extra attributes in them. Like classes and targets and so on, which works.

What I now want to do, is to adjust it so it matches and ignores any other tags inside the link itself (if there is any), as I only want the text of the link along with the address. I am unsure about the best way to do this.

Comment: It might be [better to use a DOM parser for this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Is this for a quick one-time hack on a fixed set of input data that is known to be consistent in format (i.e. consistent quotes around attributes, nothing html-like embedded inside attributes, consistent case, etc)?  If so, regexp away.  Otherwise, use a DOM parser, or prepare for an infinite loop of "found another weird edge case, made the regex more convoluted to work around it, rinse and repeat").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Always Use DOM Parsing instead of regex

This has been suggested a multitude of times. And based on the comments to the increasingly complicated regex forming, it would be easier to examine just DOM. Take the following for example:

```js
function fragmentFromString(strHTML) {
  return document.createRange().createContextualFragment(strHTML);
}

let html = `<a data-popup-text="take me to <a href='http://www.google.com'>a search engine</a>" href="testing.html" data-id="1" data-popup-text="take me to <a href='http://www.google.com'>a search engine</a>"><p>Testing <span>This</span></p></a>`;
let fragment = fragmentFromString(html);
let aTags = Array.from(fragment.querySelectorAll('a'));

aTags = aTags.map(a => {
  return {
    href: a.href,
    text: a.textContent
  }
});

console.log(aTags);
```

The above will turn a string of HTML into actual DOM inside of a fragment. You still still need to append that fragment somewhere, but the point is, that you can now query the a tags. The above code gives you an array of objects that contain the data for each `a` tag, their href value, and the innerText, minus all the html.

---

**Original answer. Don't use it, it stays to serve as context to the real problem:**

I changed this a little to use a non-greedy format (.*?). It will also avoid early ending because of ending html in an attribute as pointed out by @Gaby aka G. Petrioli.

```
<.*?href="(.*?)"(?:[^"]*")+>(.*)<\/a>
```

[Check out the JS fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/Y9Wt0L/3)

Comment: Check out this as well https://regex101.com/r/Y9Wt0L/2

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, good catch

Comment: Well, that's certainly better than what I had, but back to the original question, what about stripping out other stuff inside the >HERE</a> (as I only want the link text, not random styles and stuff applied to it and other random tags.

Comment: @NaughtySquid, are you evaluating `a` tags in the DOM, or from a string of text?

Comment: Essentially, I'm capturing a paste. What I'm using it for is changing over links from google docs, libre office and so on to bbcode tags in my textarea.

Comment: @NaughtySquid the thing is that if the supplied text to the regex is not restricted to very specific rules, then a regex will not be able to handle arbitrary inputs. That is why Scimonster's comment to the question is so upvoted.

Comment: @KevBot now look at https://regex101.com/r/Y9Wt0L/5 :p

Comment: The current version of this answer no longer matches a simple `<a href="testing.html">Testing</a>`. https://regex101.com/r/Jz4vcf/1

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli, XD It would be never-ending to go the regex route.

Comment: @DanielBeck, haha, yeah, it's time to find another solution besides regex!

Comment: @KevBot exactly. Good update !

Comment: Oh wow, that's brilliant thanks a lot, this will be useful for parsing any other tag I need to as well I guess. Never seen this before, thanks!

Comment: Okay, so I undertstand the basics of how that works, but how do I then get it to replace each one with something? Is there a place the overall capture is stored to find and replace against?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, as in replacing what it finds (so the overall a tag) in the original text with something else. I imagine I can do it within a loop like that, but I can't figure out matching up each found a tag in the original to replace....if that makes sense?

Comment: Should I make a new question with the code I have from you to help this along rather than lots of comments?

Comment: New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41270252/replacing-text-from-a-paste-when-looping-over-html-elements