# replacing text from a paste when looping over html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace html links (and eventually other elements) with bbcode when a user does a paste from a document (like gdocs or libre office). So we are dealing with rich html already formatted (which is why it needs to copy HTML and not text).

Essentially, I want to be able to copy stuff pre-written from a document into a textarea on my website without having to manually write BBCode tags in the original document (as it's messy for proof-reading).

Thanks to the help here [Adjust regex to ignore anything else inside link HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266864/adjust-regex-to-ignore-anything-else-inside-link-html-tags#41266864) I have gotten mostly there, but I am stuck on replacing the found tags with the original text.

Here's what I have:

```
function fragmentFromString(strHTML) {
  return document.createRange().createContextualFragment(strHTML);
}

  $('textarea').on('paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/html') || prompt('Paste something..');
    var fragment = fragmentFromString(text);
    var aTags = Array.from(fragment.querySelectorAll('a'));

    aTags.forEach(a => {
      text = text.replace(a, "[url="+a.href+"]"+a.textContent+"[/url]");
    });

    window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
});
```

You can see it loops over the found `a` tags and I am essentially trying to replace them from the original text with the new stuff.

Here's an example of the type of content that could be pasted (this is a single link from google docs):

```
<a href="https://www.test.com" style="text-decoration:none;"><span style="font-size:14.666666666666666px;font-family:Arial;color:#1155cc;background-color:transparent;font-weight:700;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:baseline;white-space:pre-wrap;">Link test</span></a>
```

Expected to be replaced with:

```
[url=https://www.test.com]Link test[/url]
```

So I want that HTML replaced, with the BBCode within the original text that's then sent to the textarea from the paste.

Answer (score 0):

The aTags foreach currently does nothing. You need to create a new text node, and replace the existing anchor tag with it.

```
aTags.forEach(a => {
  var new_text = document.createTextNode("[url=" + a.href + "]" + a.textContent + "[/url]");
  a.parentNode.insertBefore(new_text, a);
  a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
});

window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, text.innerText);
```

This will replace every a tag into the given text.

Comment: Let me know if that wasn't what you wanted, and I'll see if I can tweak it.

Comment: Your new edit doesn't solve actually replacing it in the text that's then presented to the user in the paste.

Comment: What do you mean by "the text that's presented to the user"?

Comment: Notice the "text" var, this is what is actually sent to the textarea for the user to interact with.

Comment: Do you want just text, or to include the remaining HTML tags?

Comment: I just want the corresponding a tags it picks up, to be replaced with the [url= tags in the text, as that's then sent to the textarea.

Comment: Right. There will be tags other than <a>. I'll assume you don't want those included in the paste.

Comment: Those will be dealt with as I expand this function to cover other tags, but I just want to get the basics working first.

Comment: Yes, but you can use `text.innerHTML` to let all non-BBcode regular HTML tags stay as HTML tags, or you can use `text.innerText` so that no HTML tags get through at all.

Comment: I've implemented no-HTML-tags in my answer.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, you're setting "new_text" but not using it anywhere, and your code would overwrite any existing text in the textbox. Please look at my original code, it's dealing with a paste into a textarea.

Comment: `new_text` is set to the new text node. That text node is then inserted into the DOM of that fragment.

Comment: Okay. So you want to use your `window.document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);` line instead. I was just guessing as to what the whole "text presented" thing was about ;P

Comment: No worries, it's easy to not get things across correctly. Sadly though, this doesn't actually work as I still get the plain full html sent to the textarea.

Comment: Ah--use `text.innerText` instead then? (see edited answer)

Comment: Nothing, it's undefined, as "text" is just a var of the full paste.

Comment: Okay. `fragment` is the DOM version, right? Use `fragment.innerText` and see if that works.

Comment: That gives nothing as well, as the "aTags" where the loop is done is created from it, it's an array by itself.

Comment: But the anchor tag DOM nodes are the same ones as in the fragment. So any change to them will be changing the fragment also. Not sure why that's not working. Could you make a quick jsFiddle so I can debug myself?

Comment: Are you trying to get just the HTML "as a string" from the fragment?

Comment: @KevBot I am trying to replace the found a html tag (within the pasted text) with the bbcode, you should be able to see what I am trying to do in the original post. To then have that adjusted text sent to the textarea.